# Record video in flv format

Tags: flash, video, rtmp

I have this video using RTMP protocol located in a web page, I need to download
it and record it, not sure which free application to use or tools to achieve
this. I was able to construct the html code to play it only using

[`platipus.nl/flvplayer/download/1.0`](http://platipus.nl/flvplayer/download/1.0)

But need to download it and record it in a DVD, any help is appreciated. Video
location

```
rtmp://frameweld.fcod.llnwd.net/a3657/o9/10/3662.flv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ rtmpdump -r rtmp://frameweld.fcod.llnwd.net/a3657/o9/10/3662.flv -o a.flv
RTMPDump v2.4-84-gdd57cd0
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
INFO: Connected...
Starting download at: 0.000 kB
[...]
11196.520 kB / 331.58 sec (3.2%)
```